# How to convert .then notation to an async function for aesthetic reasons in react

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to use an asyc function instead of fetch().then() notation for readability purposes. This is code.

```js
fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data =>
    this.setState({
      user: {
        name: data.display_name,
        href: data.external_urls.spotify
      }
    })
  )
  .catch(error => console.log("Data async function"));
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

```js
async function data() {
  const response = fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    }
  });
  const data = response.json();
  this.setState({
    user: {
      name: data.display_name,
      href: data.external_urls.spotify
    }
  })
}

data().catch(error => console.log("Data async function"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

This is how you can convert your code in to `async await` manner :

```
const your_function = async () => { 
    try{
        const res = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", { // <--- MISSING await
            headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
            }
        })
        const data = await response.json(); // <--- MISSING await
        this.setState({
            user: {
                name: data.display_name,
                href: data.external_urls.spotify
            }
        })
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Data async function"));
    }
};
```

> **NOTE :** As per you updated code you are missing `await` before all `promise` function, you can compare it will above code snippet
>
> I do suggest to cover all the code within `try catch block` whenever
>   you are using `async await`

Comment: Is the try catch block necessary or is it just best practice?

Comment: Can I replace it with this: data().catch(error => console.log("Data async function"));

Comment: @MazenMahari ,  it just best practice, if you remove try catch you can use it like , `your_function.catch()`, also read this https://stackify.com/node-js-error-handling/